# TWO ways data binding between activities

Tags: java, android

I've 2 activities, and need the `main Activity` to send some data to the `second Activity` then the second activity analyze this data and send response back, so I've the below 2 codes:

`Main Activity`:

```
    import static tk.zillion.mobile.SecondActivity.EXTRA_STUFF;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;
   private static final int SECOND_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Start the SecondActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my text");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE);

    finish();
  }

// This method is called when the second activity finishes
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "I'm the Main activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // check that it is the SecondActivity with an OK result
    if (requestCode == SECOND_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // get String data from Intent
            String returnString = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STUFF);

            // set text view with string
            Toast.makeText(this, "I'm the Main activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and the `Second Activity` is as below:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

static final String EXTRA_STUFF = "tk.zillion.mobile.EXTRA_STUFF";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    Toast.makeText(this, "I'm the second activity " + s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Bundle basket =new Bundle();
    basket.putString(EXTRA_STUFF, s);
    intent.putExtras(basket);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
  }
}
```

The second activity is fired correctly, and receive the data from the main one, but once the data is sent back the `onActivityResult` is not fired!!

How can I solve it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the finish() call that comes after startActivityForResult(). You prevent the oncoming activity to give a result back, because you remove your MainActivity with finish() from the back task.

Answer (score 2):

Dont call finish() after startActivityForResult otherwise that instance of MainActivity that started the second one will be destroyed